# Responsive CSS Clip-path using SVG even after adding objectBoundingBox

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design

```css
html, body{
   margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  background: crimson;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  Test
</div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path id="masksvg" d="M0,0H1449L828,900H0V0Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

svg clip shape path is not responsive. 
http://codepen.io/praveenvijayan/full/PZMxqG

I tried adding `objectBoundingBox`.

I created a code snippet with minimum test case. Please view it in full screen to see the mask.

SVG

```
 <svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
     <clipPath id="svgPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path id="masksvg" d="M0,0H1449L828,900H0V0Z"/> 
     </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.clip {
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
   clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

[image]

Comment: use objectBoundingBox units if you want it responsive

Comment: Tried viewBox. That is not working.

Comment: What's viewBox got to do with objectBounding box units?

Comment: clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" -  not worked.

Comment: You need to show us what you've written otherwise we don't know where you're going wrong.

Comment: http://codepen.io/praveenvijayan/pen/PZMxqG

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <path id="masksvg" d="M0,0H1449L828,900H0V0Z"/> 
      </clipPath>
</defs>
 </svg>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104422/discussion-between-praveen-vijayan-and-robert-longson).

Comment: @paul-lebeal - this is not a duplicate question. The solution mentioned there is not working for me.

Comment: The values in the path d attribute are inappropriate for objectBoundingBox units

Comment: @RobertLongson - 
I tried both values as discussed - objectBoundingBox &  userSpaceOnUse.